# Star in Bash history

Tags: bash, history

I'm just scrolling through all the commands i have recently used in computer which is running Ubuntu. I have found one line which looks like blank but i'm not sure about it it contains star right after the number of the command.

After using command `history` in terminal, It looks like this:

```
68 another command
69 another command
70 another command
71*
72 another command
73 another command
74 another command
```

what does this line mean?

```
71*
```

what command is hidden in this line ?

Comment: You may have typed `*` and hit Enter. Screamy bold is so annoying, by the way.

Comment: i have tested that that was the first thing that came into my mind , doing this will produce 71{space}* and not 71* there is difference

Comment: @mikewhatever Nope, thats shown when a command is modified after retrieving  from history.

Comment: heemayl how could i do it ? i have no idea

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This occurs when you retrieve an entry from history list by history expansion or using arrow keys and modify the entry.

From `help history`:

> Display the history list with line numbers, prefixing each modified
>   entry with a `*'.

So in your case as the command field is null, you have retrieved that entry from history file/buffer and made it null by removing the command altogether i.e. the modified command will be shown.

Comment: and if i didnot do anything like this , should i be worried of some kind of intruder on my system?

Comment: @Tomas Yes, absolutely as history expansion works only on interactive sessions unless you tell `bash` otherwise.

Comment: its strange i have just reinstalled the system and used like 3 commands to create a new directory and create a text file to make my own notes, maybe i did it but i dont remember i dont exactly understand how you described the proccess of doing it

Comment: ah i know  the problem is that i used arrow up to use previous command but i added something to the end of the command , everything is ok , no intruder , case solved